# get the sign change count from Dataframe

Tags: pandas, function

I have df like this

```
     Date            amount
 0  2021-06-18          14
 1  2021-06-19          -8
 2  2021-06-20          -8
 3  2021-06-21          17
 4  2021-07-02          -8
 5  2021-07-05          77            
 6  2021-07-06          -10
 7  2021-08-02          -78
 8  2021-08-06           77            
 9  2021-07-08          10
```

i went the count of sign change in amount month wise of count each month like  in

```
count =  [{"June-2021": 2},{"July-2021" : 3},{"Aug-2021" : 1}]

Note: Last Date of each month and first date of next month is different then count as  in different count
```

i want a function for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(x.mul(x.shift()) < 0).sum()` **(current entry multiply by last entry being negative indicates a sign change)** to get the count of sign changes within a group of `month-year`, as follows:

```
count = (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y'), sort=False)['amount']
           .agg(lambda x: (x.mul(x.shift()) < 0).sum())
           .to_dict()
        )
```

**Result:**

```
print(count)

{'Jun-2021': 2, 'Jul-2021': 3, 'Aug-2021': 1}
```

### Edit

If you want list of dict, you can use:

```
count = (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y'), sort=False)['amount']
           .agg(lambda x: (x.mul(x.shift()) < 0).sum())
           .reset_index()
           .apply(lambda x: {x['Date']: x['amount']}, axis=1)
           .to_list()
        )
```

**Result:**

```
print(count)

[{'Jun-2021': 2}, {'Jul-2021': 3}, {'Aug-2021': 1}]
```

Comment: can we check for the Only on EOD amount means in Same date we did not count as a sign change..only check for different date...so is it possible

Comment: @user14784453  In that case, you have to determine which entry to use for a date e.g. the last entry ?  A hint for you is that It will then have a further grouping on the dates and consider only the last entry by using `.last()` function.

Comment: how and where to use .last() function

Comment: @user14784453  Take a look at [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`GroupBylast()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html)

Comment: @user14784453  That's worth a separate question.  You can post a new question for that.   Note that we suppose the scope of the requirement in question is not to be constantly updating for more requirements.  Anyway, you are free to take your new requirement to new questions for all the experts here to help you.

Comment: @user14784453  You can also drop duplicates and keeping last entry by e.g. `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Date', keep='last')` to retain only the last entry within a date before you apply the solution.